# ribbon offset by 20px

Tags: html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap and wordpress to design a wordpress theme but something odd keeps happening. My css ribbons are being offset 20px to the left for some reason and the folds of the ribbon css are not showing and I have no clue why. They are both in a centered container so I'm not sure what's going on.

What's most confusing is that my other content is not offset...

If anyone has any suggestions, they would be greatly appreciated!

Here's my code:

CSS

```
/* Ribbon 
-------------------------------------------------*/

.rectangle {
    background: #7f9db9;
    height: 50px;
    width: 970px;
    position: relative;
    left:-15px;
    top: 30px;
    float: left;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.55);
  -khtml-box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.55);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.55);
    z-index: 100; /* the stack order: foreground */
}

.rectangle h2 {
    font-size: 30px;
    color: #fff;
    padding-top: 6px;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    text-align: center;
}
```

HTML

```
        <div class="row">
            <div class="rectangle"><h2>3D CSS Ribbon</h2></div>
        </div>
```

You can also view my website (in progress) here: http://noellesnotes.com/tester/

Thank you in advance for any help you are able to offer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where do you want to put the ribbon?

Try removing lines:

```
left:-15px;
top: 30px;
```

in .rectangle.